# What does this notation mean? Perhaps related to abelian group and module.

Tags: group-theory, modules

I found this in a paper, but I don't it's meaning.
Where H is an abelian group, what does $ \bigwedge ^{2} H $ mean? If H is a dual vector space, perhaps it is wedge product. But I don't know when it comes to an Abel group.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same definition
$\bigwedge^2H=(H\otimes H)/\langle \,h\otimes h\mid h\in H\, \rangle $
 with $\otimes$ meaning the tensor product as $\mathbb Z$-modules